# Why is my request returning my own html page in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a Fetch request to the konachan website to retrieve a list of tags in my react project, but it keeps returning my own html page. I've tried changing to axios and other forms of 'requesting', but it either doesn't work or returns the same thing. When I run the same request in postman it gives the actual data I need.

```
useEffect(() => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append(
        'Cookie',
        '__cfduid=de8d9ce9b68141ee863ec378052154da41610774204'
    );

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow',
    };

    fetch('konachan.com/tag.xml?limit=0', requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
}, []);
```

and i'm getting this in the console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
   
    <title>WaifuBase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I found the issue, but I still don't know what the solution is. It's calling the request from the wrong domain..

url: "http://localhost:3000/konachan.com/tag.json?limit=0"

It's trying to go from my localhost:3000 instead of the actually konachan website..

Comment: use the string with https: `https://konachan.com/tag.xml?limit=0`